# Ubuntu 14.04 Server Vim Configuration

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, vim, vimrc

I am new to Vim, however I am learning to love it. As a former/current Windows user, there is one shortcut that I depend on and would like to configure in Vim.

On windows I can use ctrl-[arrow left] and ctrl-[arrow right] to skip over words left and right.

I just don't want to press the over arrow a bunch of times when moving any text within the editor. It can be really handy to just right over four words by pressing the arrow four times (with control held down).

**Example of functionality I want**

Let's say my cursor is represented by a pipe: `|`

*Sample text:*

`The brown |fox jumped over the lazy dog.  " before pressing ctrl-[right arrow]`

`The brown fox |jumped over the lazy dog.  " after  pressing ctrl-[right arrow]`

- Has anybody else had similar interests?
- Is there an easy way to get identical/similar functionality?
- Any help would be much appreciated!
- Sorry if I messed up any terminology (let me know and I will update anything that needs fixing).

Comment: `Alt-w` and `Alt-b` (or plain `w` and `b` if you're in command mode) should jump forward / back one word

Comment: I highly suggest the vim manual - http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/ and various tutorials - http://www.openvim.com/ , https://danielmiessler.com/study/vim/#gs.AAPvh9Q

Comment: @bodhi.zazen fair enough,  "If your only tool is a hammer, everything looks like a nail", right?  I was going for consistency of usage across platforms, but I suppose I should get familiar with the tools I'm using the way they were meant to be used.